# Como validar un 404 en una pagina con un if

Tags: php, wordpress, php5, condiciones

estoy usando el siguiente codigo

```
for($pagina=50;$pagina<60;$pagina++){

$data = file_get_contents("http://www.pagina.net/?p=".$pagina);

 if ( preg_match('|<h2 class="titulo">(.*?)</h2>|is' , $data , $cap ) )
{

    echo '<br><b>'.$cap[1] .'</b>';
}

}
?>
```

En caso de que una pagina por ejemplo : www.pagina.net/?php="200" me de una error 404 not found como haria para identificarlo en php y hacer una condicion if?

Algo asi :

```
if( $data = 404 not found)
{ echo "no rastrear" }
else { seguir rastreando }
```

Le agardezco su ayuda

Comment: Creo que eso debes realizarlo con el archivo .htaccess, al redireccionar a la pagina de error puedes hacer el if dentro

Comment: Un modo sencillo es usar curl en lugar de file_get_contents, ya que curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) te da directamente el código, sólo tienes que preguntar si es 404

Answer (score 0):

En wordpress…

```
<?php
    if ( is_404() ) {
        echo "no rastrear"
    } else {
        // Seguir Rastreando
    }
?>
```